# Building Qt 5.15.2 with MinGW-W64 gcc 12.2.0 fails with an undefined reference linking error

Tags: qt, build, compiler-errors, qt5, mingw-w64

I have been trying to build Qt 5.15.2 with MinGW-W64 gcc 12.2.0 with no avail. In each failure, I had to patch the file in question and restart again.
Here are the patches I did so far:

in the file:

```txt
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\src\corelib\io\qfilesystemengine_win.cpp
```

I had Fix:

```cpp
#if defined(Q_CC_MINGW) && WINVER < 0x0602 //  Windows 8 onwards
```

to

```cpp
#if defined(Q_CC_MINGW) && WINVER < 0x0602 && _WIN32_WINNT < _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8 //  Windows 8 onwards
```

in all the following files:

```txt
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\src\3rdparty\angle\src\libANGLE\HandleAllocator.cpp
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\src\corelib\text\qbytearraymatcher.h
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\src\corelib\global\qfloat16.h
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\src\3rdparty\masm\yarr\Yarr.h
```

I had to `#include <limits>`

But when I came across this link error, I couldn't find the cause at all, here are the last two lines from the output:

```txt
g++ -Wl,-s -shared -Wl,-subsystem,console -Wl,--out-implib,C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5QuickTest.a -o ..\..\lib\Qt5QuickTest.dll .obj/release/quicktest.o .obj/release/quicktestresult.o .obj/release/qt5quicktest_qmltyperegistrations.o .obj/release/moc_quicktest_p.o  C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Test.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Widgets.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Gui.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Core.a .obj\release\Qt5QuickTest_resource_res.o C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5Quick.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Gui.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5QmlModels.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5Qml.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Core.a
```

```txt
C:/MinGW-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: .obj/release/qt5quicktest_qmltyperegistrations.o:qt5quicktest_qmltyperegistrations.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN11QQmlPrivate12ConstructorsI15QTestRootObjectLb1EE23createSingletonInstanceE[.refptr._ZN11QQmlPrivate12ConstructorsI15QTestRootObjectLb1EE23createSingletonInstanceE]+0x0): undefined reference to `QQmlPrivate::Constructors<QTestRootObject, true>::createSingletonInstance'
```

and here is the configure command I used:

```txt
configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -nomake tests -strip -c++std c++11 -skip qtwebengine -prefix %CD%\gcc_dll
```

then

```txt
mingw32-make
```

Seems like the build stopped at an end before crashing this link error, because I can see a bunch of built libraries that are:

```txt
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\Qt5QuickShapes.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\Qt5Quick.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\Qt5QmlWorkerScript.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\Qt5QmlModels.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\Qt5Qml.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtsvg\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtsvg\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtsvg\lib\Qt5Svg.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\qtvectorcanbus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\qtsysteccanbus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\qttinycanbus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\qtpeakcanbus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\qtpassthrucanbus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\qtvirtualcanbus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\lib\Qt5SerialBus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialport\lib\Qt5SerialPort.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtnetworkauth\lib\Qt5NetworkAuth.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\styleplugin\release\styles\simplestyleplugin.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\plugandpaint\plugins\pnp_extrafilters.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\echoplugin\plugins\echoplugin.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\styles\qwindowsvistastyle.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\generic\qtuiotouchplugin.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platformthemes\qxdgdesktopportal.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\qdirect2d.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\bearer\qgenericbearer.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlodbc.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5OpenGL.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5PrintSupport.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Concurrent.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5DBus.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Test.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Widgets.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Gui.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libEGL.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libGLESv2.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Xml.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Sql.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Network.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\Qt5Core.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\gnuwin32\lib\regex2.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\gnuwin32\lib\libintl3.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\gnuwin32\lib\libiconv2.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\gnuwin32\lib\libcharset1.dll
C:\Dev\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\third_party\crashpad\crashpad\handler\win\z7_test.dll

C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5QuickTest.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5QuickShapes.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5Quick.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5QmlWorkerScript.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5QmlModels.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtdeclarative\lib\libQt5Qml.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtsvg\plugins\iconengines\libqsvgicon.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtsvg\plugins\imageformats\libqsvg.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtsvg\lib\libQt5Svg.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtactiveqt\lib\libQt5AxServer.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtactiveqt\lib\libQt5AxContainer.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtactiveqt\lib\libQt5AxBase.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\libqicns.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\libqwebp.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\libqtiff.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\libqwbmp.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtimageformats\plugins\imageformats\libqtga.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\libqtvectorcanbus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\libqtsysteccanbus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\libqttinycanbus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\libqtpeakcanbus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\libqtpassthrucanbus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\plugins\canbus\libqtvirtualcanbus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialbus\lib\libQt5SerialBus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtserialport\lib\libQt5SerialPort.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtnetworkauth\lib\libQt5NetworkAuth.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\styleplugin\release\styles\libsimplestyleplugin.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\plugandpaint\plugins\libpnp_extrafilters.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\plugandpaint\plugins\libpnp_basictools.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\examples\widgets\tools\echoplugin\plugins\libechoplugin.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\printsupport\libwindowsprintersupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\styles\libqwindowsvistastyle.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\generic\libqtuiotouchplugin.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\imageformats\libqgif.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\imageformats\libqjpeg.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\imageformats\libqico.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platformthemes\libqxdgdesktopportal.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\libqdirect2d.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\libqwindows.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\libqoffscreen.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\platforms\libqminimal.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\bearer\libqgenericbearer.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlite.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlodbc.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5OpenGL.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5PrintSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5OpenGLExtensions.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5WindowsUIAutomationSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5AccessibilitySupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5EglSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5PlatformCompositorSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5FontDatabaseSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5ThemeSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5FbSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5DeviceDiscoverySupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5EventDispatcherSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5EdidSupport.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libqtfreetype.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Concurrent.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5DBus.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Test.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Widgets.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Gui.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libqtlibpng.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\liblibEGL.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\liblibGLESv2.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libtranslator.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libpreprocessor.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libqtharfbuzz.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Xml.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Sql.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Network.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libqtmain.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Core.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libqtpcre2.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\lib\libQt5Bootstrap.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\ppapi\native_client\src\untrusted\irt_stub\libppapi.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\chromium\third_party\breakpad\breakpad\src\client\mac\gcov\libgcov.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\io\qdir\types\c.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\io\qdir\types\b.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\io\qdir\types\a.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\io\qdir\types\f.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\io\qdir\types\e.a
C:\Dev\qt5\qtbase\tests\auto\corelib\io\qdir\types\d.a
```

I gave up so I posted here.
May be someone ran across this issue before, and could share his solution or workaround.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a lower version of MinGW will work.
You could find the toolchains used in Qt binary packages in this page:https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW.